# Table format conversion

Tags: tables, formatting

I use the following template for KDD 2017 - for conference [here](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) (sample-sigconf file): 
 Here is my table: [image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c||} 
        \hline
        ID & das dfdas Nafdsme & abc fds & adfsdd  & fsd fds& fasd fas   \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline\hline
        DS1 & fdsr fsda & 0.0006946 & 0.02436 & 0.0019150   & 0.2039 \\ 
        DS2 & fas       & 0.0011914 & 0.05942 & -0.0003213  & 0.001561 \\
        DS3 & fsd       & 4.900e-06 & 0.2318  & 2.487e-05   & 0.7709 \\
        DS4 & sadfaCfds & 2.523e-05 & 0.1555  & 8.027e-04   & 0.5613 \\ [1ex] 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{bfdsaasdfk  fdsljkjl}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}
```

However, I would like to change it to the following format:
[image]

This is my source code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
        \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
            \toprule
            \thead{ID}  &   \thead{Udsffsd fdsdfs fdse} 
            &   {\thead{sdffds \\(fds)}}
            &   {\thead{fds \\(fs)}} 
            &   {\thead{Classes\\(fs)}}           \\
            \midrule
            DS1 & asd fdsdf                          & 1025010  & 11    & 9     \\
            DS2 & abcd                                & 5000000  & 18    & 2     \\
            DS3 & fsdgfsdg fgsd fdsfd fsdsffd g       & 5749132  & 9     & 2     \\
            DS4 & das ds dsds                         & 4898431  & 42    & 23    \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{bksdfhkadf sdfljj lasdflkj}
        \label{table:1}
    \end{table}
```

Every trial I did to convert the above to this one yields error. How can I convert the upper table to the required format (the second one)?

Comment: What you  want is not very clear: is it converting the first source-code using the second code as a model?

Comment: Yes exactly! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The screenshots you've posted are microscopic in size and nearly unreadable. Please post new, bigger screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, @Mico, please press the screenshot you will see it 1:1.

Comment: @Avi you could crop the pdf with minimal effort for you, making it much easier for every reader.

Comment: When I click on the screenshots, I basically get the same minuscule and barely legible screenshots, the only difference being that they're now on a screen all by themselves. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Note table captions, traditionally, should be *above* their table.

I use the `S` column type  for conveniently formatted  and aligned cells with numerical values. To center non-numerical values (such as column heads) in `S` columns, put them between a pair of brackets. I also use `booktabs` to have variable-thickness rules with some vertical padding. Never use vertical rules in table with booktabs rules (unless you know what you do).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx, caption, float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \sisetup{table-format=1.3e-2, table-alignment=center, tight-spacing}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X cSS[table-format=1.5] SS[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    ID & das dfdas Nafdsme & {abc fds} & {adfsdd} & {fsd fds} & {fasd fas} \\ [0.5ex]
    \midrule
    DS1 & fdsr fsda & 0.0006946 & 0.02436 & 0.0019150 & 0.2039 \\
    DS2 & fas & 0.0011914 & 0.05942 & -0.0003213 & 0.001561 \\
    DS3 & fsd & 4.900e-06 & 0.2318 & 2.487e-05 & 0.7709 \\
    DS4 & sadfaCfds & 2.523e-05 & 0.1555 & 8.027e-04 & 0.5613 \\ [1ex]
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{bfdsaasdfk fdsljkjl}
  \label{table:3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's why I didn't add detailed explanations

Comment: I thought a slightly bigger clue would be needed, but it's your answer so I've deleted my comment.  Lets see what the OP makes of it.

Comment: No, you're. I forgot the O.P. didn't use siunitx. I'll complete my answer.